# Path integral measure Fourier transformation for case of real field

Tags: fourier-transform, path-integral, complex-numbers

Let's have
$$
Z[J] = \int D \varphi e^{iS[\varphi , J]},
$$
where $\varphi$ denotes real scalar field. Let's make Fourier transform,
$$
\varphi (x) = \int e^{iqx}\varphi (q), \quad \varphi^{*} (q) = \varphi (-q).
$$
How to prove that under this transformation the measure will change as
$$
\tag 1 D \varphi \to D {\rm Im}(\varphi (q))D{\rm Re}(\varphi (q))?
$$
Especially I'm interested in explanation of transition
$$
D\varphi (x) \to \left[D\varphi (q)D\varphi^{*}(q)\right]_{\varphi^{*}(q) = \varphi (-q)}.
$$
I expect that condition $\varphi^{*}(q) = \varphi (-q)$ implies delta function which simply drops integration over $\varphi^{*}$, but it seems that $(1)$ says that 
mentioned condition don't drop integration, as is written by Ali Moh.

Answer (score 1):

since $\phi(x)$ is real, $\phi^*(q) =  \phi(-q)$ implies Re$(\phi(q))$ is even and Im$(\phi(q))$ is odd, but nonetheless independent unlike the real and imaginary parts of $\phi(x)$. So in the new measure it must be understood that you are summing only over the even/odd functions.

There for $\mathcal{D}\phi(q)\mathcal{D}\phi^*(q)\rightarrow\mathcal{D}\phi(q)\mathcal{D}\phi(-q)\propto \mathcal{D}\phi_{\text{even}}(q)\mathcal{D}\phi_{\text{odd}}(q)\rightarrow\mathcal{D}\text{Re}\phi(q)\mathcal{D}\text{Im}\phi(q)$

Where in the 2nd step we used
\begin{align}
\phi_{\text{even}}= \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\phi(q) + \phi(-q)\right) \\
\phi_{\text{even}}= \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\phi(q) - \phi(-q)\right) 
\end{align}
And proportionality is the constant jacobian factor of this linear transformation

Comment: Thank you! But what about transformation $D\varphi \to D \varphi (q)D\varphi^{*}(q)$?

Comment: There will be something like Vandermonde determinant in continuous space (which is expected to be equal to 1) and formal increasing of number of independent variables of integration (instead of $\varphi(x)$ there will be $\varphi(q), \varphi^{*}(q)$. So maybe it is needed some delta-function which make bound?

Comment: You want $\phi_{\text{odd}}$.